# Could not import setuptools which is required to install from a source distribution. Please install setuptools

Tags: python, python-3.x, setuptools

I'm trying to install a specific tool that is written in Python. In order to install it I need to run :

```
python3.6 setup build
python3.6 setup install
```

However when I run it I'm getting the next warnings :

```
/usr/lib64/python3.6/distutils/dist.py:261: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'install_requires'
warnings.warn(msg)
/usr/lib64/python3.6/distutils/dist.py:261: UserWarning: Unknown distribution 
option: 'setup_requires'
warnings.warn(msg)
/usr/lib64/python3.6/distutils/dist.py:261: UserWarning: Unknown distribution 
option: 'tests_require'
warnings.warn(msg)
```

So I tried to install setuptools from a local file that I downloaded from the pypi :

```
python3.6 -m pip install setuptools-39.2.0.zip 
Processing ./setuptools-39.2.0.zip
Could not import setuptools which is required to install from a source     distribution.
Please install setuptools.
```

I tried to install the whl file as suggested in the comments:

```
 pip3.6 install setuptools-40.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl 
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools==40.0.0 from     file:///PostgreSQL/installs/setuptools-40.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
```

But still, got the same error when trying to install the Python tool. What can I do ?

Note: something that I realized now, when I try to build the tool with different user (that is not root) I'm not getting those errors however the python3.6 setup.py install part fails because the user doesn't have privileges. So, why for root it fails ?

Comment: Can you install them from `pip`?  Try `python3.6 -m pip install --upgrade setuptools`

Comment: I cant because I dont have access to the internet from my server

Comment: Download & install the setuptools wheel (.whl), not the zip.

Comment: @jwodder this should be the answer instead of what's posted currently.

Comment: I installed it : pip3.6 install setuptools-40.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl 
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools==40.0.0 from file:///PostgreSQL/installs/setuptools-40.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages But I get the same error when trying to build / install the python tool

Answer (score 1):

If you have internet access you can install python3-setuptools using your OS package manager:

OpenSuSE/SLES:
`zypper in python3-setuptools`

CentOS:
`yum install python3-setuptools`

Debian/Ubuntu:
`apt-get install python3-setuptools`

Comment: I dont have access to the internet from the server

Answer (score 0):

if you use any linux base Debian, use:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

This will install all the necessary packages.

Comment: Makes sense, sorry

Answer (score -1):

I had a problem with my PATH variable. Changing it to the PATH of the other user solved it for me.